# RecyclerView listitem row are wrapping inside view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-tablelayout, android-layout-weight

Layout implementation

[image]

I have implemented a RecyclerView and set the following ListItem to it. Layout Implementation is how i am getting the output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/partspricinglistheader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:weightSum="6">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemno_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemdescription_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_mrp_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="MRP"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemquantity_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Set/Quantity"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_margincd_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="MARGIN"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemcat_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CAT"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I even used `android:stretchColumns="*"` using TableLayout, Couldn't set the item row as required in the image.

Comment: Try to change `android:layout_width` from *"wrap_content"* to *"0dp"* in your `TextView`s.

Comment: Changing  android:layout_width and android:layout_weight helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:stretchColumns="6">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemno_tv"
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemdescription_tv"
            android:layout_width="0.5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_mrp_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:text="MRP"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemquantity_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Set/Quantity"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_margincd_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MARGIN"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemcat_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="CAT"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_width` from `"wrap_content"` to `"0dp"` in your `TextView`s.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/partspricinglistheader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:weightSum="6">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemno_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Item"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemdescription_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_mrp_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="MRP"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemquantity_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Set/Quantity"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_margincd_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="MARGIN"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="38dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pp_itemcat_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="CAT"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: This didn't work, I have used static weight and height separately for each TextView's.

Comment: OK, so post your solution for future users.